# React Native Maps - Null Object Reference

Tags: react-native-maps

I'm following this tutorial on React Native Maps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MqLC0kOqrwk&t=1s

My code is near identical to the tutors (I didn't use `MapView.Markers`) but I get this error: **Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean
abi19_0_0.com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap.hasKey(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference**

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get ('window')

const SCREEN_HEIGHT = height
const SCREEN_WIDTH = width
const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height

const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0922
const LONGTITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO

export default class MapScreen extends React.Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super (props)

        this.state = {
            initialPosition: {
                latitude: 0,
                longitude: 0,
                latitudeDelta: 0,
                longitudeDelta: 0,
            }
        }
    }

    watchID: ?number = null

    componentDidMount () {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition ((position) => {
            var lat = parseFloat (position.coords.latitude)
            var long = parseFloat (position.coords.longitude)

            var initialRegion = {
                latitude: lat,
                longitude: long,
                latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                longitudeDelta: LONGTITUDE_DELTA
            }

            this.setState ({ initialPosition: initialRegion })
        },
        (error) => alert (JSON.stringify (error)),
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 })

        this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition ((position) => {
            var lat = parseFloat (position.coords.latitude)
            var long = parseFloat (position.coords.longitude)

            var lastRegion = {
                latitude: lat,
                longitude: long,
                latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                longitudeDelta: LONGTITUDE_DELTA
            }

            this.setState ({ initialPosition: lastRegion })
        })
    }

    componentWillUnmount () {
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch (this.watchID)
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <MapView
                style = { styles.mapContainer }
                region = {this.state.initialPosition}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check the compatibilty of react-native and react-native-maps. There are issues with the latest 0.47 version. Which version of react-native and RNMaps are you using? Try RN v. 0.44 - it seems quite stable now.

Comment: RN: 0.46.1, RNMaps: 0.16.0
I've tried updating and relinking but got nothing. Will try again with RN 0.44.

Comment: Made a project with RN 0.44.0 and ran into Android SDK issues which aren't present in the latest version. I'm gonna stick with the latest.

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to the question. This is to avoid confusion for future visitors. You can see in your [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45559887/revisions) that I have rolled back this change.

Comment: Thanks @Bugs! I'd been wondering how I should be handling this situation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this working in a new `react-native init` project (RN 0.47.1, RNMaps 0.16.0) with the following added to **./android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml**:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

`<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
android:value="WHATEVERYOURAPIKEYIS" />`